# Check if item is in list

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose, I have a table in the following format:

```
CowId    Farm    Week1
1        CB      c("Staphylococcus aureus", "Escherichia coli")
2        CB      No Growth
3        CB      NA
4        CB      Staphylococcus aureus
```

How can I check if Staphylococcus aureus is a member of the Week1 column?  I tried

```
dt.wide %>%
    filter(Week1 %in% "Staphylococcus aureus")
```

But it only captures CowId 4, not CowId 1.  Any feedback would be helpful.

```
dt.wide <- structure(list(CowId = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), 
                          Farm = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                          .Label = c("CB", "CB", "CB", "CB"), 
                          class = "factor"), 
                          Week1 = list(c("Staphylococcus aureus", "Escherichia coli"), "No Growth", NA, "Staphylococcus aureus")), 
                          row.names = c(NA, -4L), 
                          class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(dt.wide)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(dt.wide, 20))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yes, of course.  Interesting, I was not aware of this function.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if 'Staphylococcus aureus' is a member of the Week1 column without retaining what is inside the list. This approach will work.

You first `unnest` the column, apply your filters and if you want to, you can always nest again:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  unnest(Week1) %>% 
  filter(Week1 %in% "Staphylococcus aureus")
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R approach :

```
subset(dt.wide, sapply(Week1, function(x) "Staphylococcus aureus" %in% x))

#   CowId Farm  Week1    
#  <int> <fct> <list>   
#1     1 CB    <chr [2]>
#2     4 CB    <chr [1]>
```